# Check comments on Wordpress with SQL query and Nagios

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, mariadb, nagios

For my homework project I need to oversee a web server and a wordpress website on it with a Nagios server. Both are LAMP Debian 9 server, all is setup and working.

I'm using Nagios XI and MariaDB with the default wordpress database explain [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_comments).

For the last part I need to check all comments posted in the last 4 hours to avoid a Spam campaign. I need a warning threshold set on 4 comments in last 4 hours, and a critical threshold set on 10 comments in last 4 hours.

I found [check_mysql_query.pl](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Databases/check_mysql_query-2Epl-(Advanced-Nagios-Plugins-Collection)/details) plugin for Nagios. 
But I'am a little bit lost for making work this with a SQL query. According to wordpress doc, I try  something like :

```
SELECT comment-date FROM wp-comments WHERE comment-data > ($current_time - 4h00)
```

I want to extract the number of new comment add to databases the last 4 hours.

I don't know the sytaxe for `($current_time - 4h00)`

And for my plugin command I have something like :

```
./check_mysql_query.pl -H 192.168.0.1 -u user -p password -d wordpress -q mysqlquery -w 4 -c 10
```

That's where I am, but the method is free, so if you know how complete this command (with some basics explanations please), it's great. But if you know other ways to do that, I'd be happy to see them too. Thanks.

Comment: we don’t know your schema. Please supply the structure, sample data, desired output.

Comment: The structure of the Data Base is the default structure of a wordpress website and the DB name is wordpress [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_comments) so comments are store in the wp_comments table. I do not know what output I need to do what is described above, that my point (I'm a SQL beginner sorry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok with the help from the Ярослав Машко I found the perfect commande. What it was awnsered give out a list of comments posted in last 4 hours. This was not exactly the need because it was unusable by Nagios plugins to put a threshold alert. So to have the number of comments in last four hours I've put a count() in th SQL request. This is the good way for me :

```
SELECT COUNT(c.comment_date) FROM wp_comments as c where hour(timediff( localtime(), c.comment_date ) ) < 4;
```

I've put this in the check_mysql_query plugin (native in Nagios XI) and it's working fine. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t have a time to check all Wordpress database schema. But from your SQL query, I think you need following

```
select comment-date
from wp-comments
where hour( localtime() - comment-date ) < 4
;
```

**update**

Must had added that I don’t know MySQL syntax. The right thing should be

```
select comment-date
from wp-comments
where hour(timediff( localtime(), comment-date ) ) < 4
;
```

Comment: Thanks for this it could be that but the output is really random : ```MariaDB [wordpress]> SELECT comment_date FROM wp_comments WHERE hour( localtime() - comment_date ) < 4; ``` if I enter five time this i get ```3 rows in set ``` -- ```2 rows in set 1 warning``` -- ```2 rows in set 1 warning``` --  ```1 rows in set 3 warning``` -- ```Empty set, 4 warnings```

Comment: The reason for the strange time is that you cannot reliably subtract datetime values with simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

This will count how comments are attributed to user 123 in the last 4 hours:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM wp_comments
    WHERE comment_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 4 HOUR
      AND user_id = 123;
```

(Caveat:  Without seeing `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, I cannot be sure of what columns exist.  If you really use dash (`-`) in table and column names, be sure to put backtics around such name.)

`0h400` is not known to MySQL.

MySQL has `NOW()`, which is probably what you meant by `$current_time`.

Datetime arithmetic is best done by the pattern I show in the above SQL.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I was finishing improving Ярослав Машко's answer when I read yours.